# ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested - String Parameter more than 4000 characters in "IN" clause

Tags: sql, oracle, parameters, oracle11g, prepared-statement

I am getting ORA-01460 : unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested, in following example

/* Code snippet Java */

```
sql = "Select \"TESTDB\".\"CUSTOMER\".\"CUSTOMER_DETAIL_ID\" From \"TESTDB\".\"CUSTOMER\" WHERE \"TESTDB\".\"CUSTOMER\".\"CUSTOMER_DETAIL_ID\" in (?)";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    String input = "'8374859673849570','8374859673849557',...... more than 6000 characters"
ps.setString(1, input);
ps.executeQuery();
```

/* code snippet end */

As soon as I shorten the length of input to less than 4000 it works. 
Database table column have cusstomer ids(VARCHAR2). 
Options for me is either I build a plain sql using input in sql query itself and execute it without using any placeholders or break the input string into parts and execute it separately and then combine the result. Can anybody suggest perfect way to solve this problem? If I can increase the max characters settings in parameters. 
I tried to increase the size using OraclePreparedStatement.defineParameterTypeChars but it didn't work.
I also tried using preparedStatement.setBlob(..),setClob(..),setCharacterStream(..) nothing works.  Please help me on this

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using?

Comment: You can't pass a comma separated string to the `IN` clause in a PreparedStatement. You need to have one `?` for each element and call `setString()` once for each parameter.

Comment: In SQL, as in most languages, there is a difference between passing multiple values vs passing a *single* string value that happens to contain quotation marks and/or commas. In common with most languages, even if you succeed here, all you've done is pass a single string value as an argument for `IN()`.

Comment: Create a temp table with those values,JOIN on it

Comment: A side note: Why all those quotes? Your schema, table and column names are fine without them. You could simply write `"select customer_detail_id from testdb.customer where customer_detail_id in (?)"`.

Comment: using oracle 11g and ojdbc6-11g.jar

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned you are passing a single string as an argument to in, resulting in something like this

```
in ('''8374859673849570'',''8374859673849557'',......,''1234567890123456''')
```

where you really want this

```
in ('8374859673849570','8374859673849557',......,'1234567890123456')
```

One way to achieve this is simple string concatenation:

```
sql = "Select \"TESTDB\".\"CUSTOMER\".\"CUSTOMER_DETAIL_ID\" From \"TESTDB\".\"CUSTOMER\" WHERE \"TESTDB\".\"CUSTOMER\".\"CUSTOMER_DETAIL_ID\" in (" +
      "'8374859673849570','8374859673849557',...... more than 6000 characters" +
      ")";

PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.executeQuery();
```

BTW: There is also a limit on `IN` in Oracle that there must not be more than 1000 elements in `IN`. You seem to have some 400 only, so no problem here, but that would be a problem once you want more elements. One solution for this problem is multiple in clauses: `where (x in (...) or x in (...))`. But this shows Oracle has problems with large `IN` clauses, so it's usually better to create a table temporarily where you insert the values and use this instead.

Comment: As I said earlier by using plain sql this works fine. Problem for me is I am receiving list of comma separated ids(input) and need to make a query by putting it in "IN" clause. So trying to create reusable prepared statement so that just changing the parameter values I get the results every time with different batches of input ids..

Comment: But you *can* build a comma-separated string from the values (as you are already doing), so you *can* concatenate it to get a final query string. Where is the problem? The statement is not reusable, but who cares? Create a new one each time. (As mentioned you may have to use a loop to create several `OR` clauses, though.) An alternative would be, as also mentioned, to use a temporary table and create an insert statement with the values instead. Same technique.

Comment: My input file is like: 1||"'2313123','12312231223','3447567566765'"                        2||"'827658745','983426743','34658734'"                                                         3||"378462876384','76238476234','88974587345'" ....and more rows further.. so I need to process one row at a time and need to provide results  for each row. Thats the reason I want to use reusable prepared statment and avoid creating new one for every row

Comment: Is there any way to pass input in single parameter and query gets generated like the way you are suggesting to create plain query??

Comment: No. There is no way to pass many parameters as one parameter. And even if you could, you would loop and call `setString` and `executeQuery` within, whereas I'd suggest you loop and call `createStatement` and `executeQuery`. Is that so much of a difference? Do you fear that `createStatement` takes a microsecond longer than `setString`? Well, you don't have much of a choice anyway. You could prepare a statement with exactly thousand `?` and call `setString` a thousand times, setting it to some not used value (e.g. 'XXX') for not needed parameters. But what the heck?